# How to change ownership of a smartsheet using smartsheet C# SDK?

Tags: c#, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-c#-sdk-v2

I have created an array of shares. This includes old owners' share and new owner share. I have updated access level = Admin for old owner. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this scenario in [Postman](https://www.postman.com) by submitting the following **Update Share** request (to change a user's access level from ADMIN to OWNER):

```
PUT https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/4211916227192708/shares/ABDCXOV-FOeE
{
    "accessLevel": "OWNER"
}
```

And the API response was:

```
{
    "errorCode": 1026,
    "message": "Transferring ownership is not currently supported.",
    "refId": "15mps6onxlivn"
}
```

This implies that the Smartsheet API does not currently support transferring ownership of a Sheet. Since the C# SDK is simply a wrapper around the API, it won't be possible to change sheet ownership using the SDK.